# close question - My two questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Question 1:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/37917/new-standard-http-protocol

My question was closed because it is not constructive.

As I understand it or it was closed for not being constructive indeed.
Or because it would generate an extensive discussion.

I disagree with both situations
The question is constructive and can be used but can be useful for many people.
Will only generate discussion if the person answering unsure own answer.

Would like to know the real reason for the question was closed.
Thanks.

---

Question 2: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/licensing-javascript-code

Honestly, I do not understand why my question was closed? This is not a discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I can provide insight into why your questions were closed (and, in any case, meta is the best place to discuss - thank you for bringing this discussion to meta).

---

**Question #1**

> Will only generate discussion if the person answering unsure own answer.

Your question stated "Why are they doing this[?]" which invites speculation. This wording is likely why it was closed as "not constructive".

[Absolute URLs omitting the protocol (scheme) in order to preserve the one of the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the) is approximately the same question - asked in a different way - and answered at StackOverflow over a year ago.

---

**Question #2**

> I do not understand why my question was closed?

This question was closed as "off topic" because it is not covered by the topics listed in our [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#questions):

> If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you
>   control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript,
>   or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow. We prefer
>   questions here about problems or issues that affect entire websites.

Comment: Question[2]: Where then should I post questions about licenses (SO also seems not be accepted), thanks.

Comment: I would recommend that you check out the [Open Source Initiative's discussion mailing list](http://opensource.org/lists) and their [FAQ](http://opensource.org/faq).

Comment: ♦ My question is simple!
The answer would be like, "Yes, that's all you need", "NO, you need to ________". You think maybe I should ask this in SO, would be more appropriate?

Comment: That may be the answer you were expecting, however, webmasters are not necessarily experts on open source licensing (which is why I would defer to those that are for an explanation of open source licensing requirements and practices).

Comment: ♦ I agree, grateful for the explanation. Thanks.